# Subset of UNIX standard tar implementation

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, linux, posix

I recently implemented a subset of the ustar archiving utility as my first year programming one project. I would like to get it reviewed and if anyone has anything to point out.

**dir.c**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "star.h"
void dir_untar(struct header_ustar *h)
{
    mode_t mode;
    char modeoct[9] = {0};
    strncpy(modeoct,h->mode,8);
    sscanf(modeoct,"%o",&mode);
    char filename[260]={0};
        if(h->prefix[0]){
        strncat(filename,h->prefix,155);
        strcat(filename,"/");
    }
    strncat(filename,h->name,100);
    mkdir(filename,mode);
}
void dir_tar(FILE *tarf, char *dirname, struct stat *s)
{
    struct header_ustar h;
    bzero(&h,sizeof(struct header_ustar));
    int len = (int)strlen(dirname);
    if(len>255)
        return;
    if(len>100){
        int j=154;
        while(dirname[j]!='/')
            j--;
        if(len-j>100)
            return;
        strncpy(h.prefix,dirname,(size_t)j);
        strncpy(h.name,dirname+j+1,(size_t)(len-j-1));
    }else
        strcpy(h.name,dirname);
    char *buf=malloc(sizeof(char)*512);
    sprintf(buf,"%08o",s->st_uid);
    strncpy(h.uid,buf,8);
    sprintf(buf,"%08o",s->st_gid);
    strncpy(h.gid,buf,8);
    sprintf(buf,"%012o",0);
    strncpy(h.size,buf,12);
    sprintf(buf,"%012o",(int)s->st_mtime);
    strncpy(h.mtime,buf,12);
    h.typeflag = '5';
    sprintf(buf,"%08o",s->st_mode);
    strncpy(h.mode,buf,8);
    strcpy(h.magic,MAGIC);
    strncpy(h.version,"00",2);
    unsigned int chksum = checksum(&h);
    sprintf(h.checksum,"%06o",chksum);
    h.checksum[7] = ' ';
    fwrite(&h,sizeof(struct header_ustar),1,tarf);

    DIR *dp;
    dp = opendir(dirname);

    struct dirent * content;
    while((content= readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(content->d_name,"..")==0 || strcmp(content->d_name,".")==0)
            continue;
        struct stat s2;
        char filename[255]={0};
        strcat(filename,dirname);
        int l2 = (int)strlen(filename);
        if(filename[l2-1]!='/'){
            filename[l2] = '/';
            filename[l2+1]= 0;
        }
        strcat(filename,content->d_name);
        stat(filename,&s2);
        if (S_ISREG(s2.st_mode))
            regular_tar(tarf,filename,&s2);
        else if(S_ISDIR(s2.st_mode))
            dir_tar(tarf,filename,&s2);
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
```

**Doxyfile** (almost automatically generated and I just wanted to know if their is any option I missed out there)

```
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "star"
PROJECT_NUMBER         =0.1
PROJECT_BRIEF          ="subset of Unix standard tar"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       =docs
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       =
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        =
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    =
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                =
TCL_SUBST              =
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      =
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       =
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    =
LAYOUT_FILE            =
CITE_BIB_FILES         =
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           =
INPUT                  = dir.c general.c help.c main.c regular.c tar.c untar.c star.h
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          =
RECURSIVE              = NO
EXCLUDE                =
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       =
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        =
EXAMPLE_PATH           =
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       =
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             =
INPUT_FILTER           =
FILTER_PATTERNS        =
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS =
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE =
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          =
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            =
HTML_FOOTER            =
HTML_STYLESHEET        =
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  =
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       =
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               =
HHC_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     =
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               =
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   =
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHG_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     =
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       =
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       =
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = NO
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = NO
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

**general.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "star.h"
int file_exist(char *path)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(path,"r");
    if (fp){
        fclose(fp);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
int isvalid_tar (const struct header_ustar *h)
{
    unsigned int n;
    sscanf(h->checksum,"%o",&n);
    return n==checksum(h)   &&
        (strcmp(h->magic,MAGIC)+1)%2;
}
unsigned int checksum (const struct header_ustar *h)
{
    unsigned int chksum=' '*8;
    unsigned int i;
    const unsigned char *hp = (unsigned char*)h;
    for(i=0;i<offsetof(struct header_ustar,checksum);i++)
        chksum+=hp[i];
    for(i+=(unsigned int)sizeof(char)*8;i<sizeof(struct header_ustar);i++)
        chksum +=hp[i];
    return chksum;
}
```

**help.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "star.h"
void show_help(void)
{
    char help[HELP_MAX+1];
    FILE *helpf;
    helpf = fopen("help.doc","r");
    if(!helpf){
        puts("Can't open help.doc");
        return;
    }
    int len= (int)(fread(help,sizeof(char),HELP_MAX,helpf)/sizeof(char));
    help[len]='\0';
    printf("%s",help);
    fclose(helpf);
}
```

**help.doc**

```c
Usage:
    star
        print help
    star output.tar input1 input2 input3...
        creates archive
    star input.tar
        extract archive
```

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "star.h"
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    switch(argc){
    case 1:
        show_help();
        break;
    case 2:
        untar(argv[1]);
        break;
    default:
        tar(argc-1,&argv[1]);
    }
    argv++;
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```c
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Werror -std=gnu99 -fverbose-asm  -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion
GDBFLAGS= -g -ggdb -ggdb3
.PHONY: all clean docs help
help:
    @echo "make [target]";
    @echo "list of possible targets";
    @echo "install : intall the binaries to /opt";
    @echo "remove  : remove the installed files";
    @echo "all     : release build";
    @echo "docs    : build  the documentation";
    @echo "debug   : debug build";
    @echo "clean   : clean directory from all builds"
remove:
    \rm -rf /opt/star /bin/star
install: all
    mkdir /opt/star/
    cp star /opt/star
    cp help.doc /opt/star
    ln /opt/star/star /bin/star
all:star
docs:
    doxygen
star: main.o help.o tar.o untar.o general.o regular.o dir.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) *.o -o star
    strip star
main.o: main.c star.h 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) main.c -o main.o
help.o: help.c star.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) help.c -o help.o
tar.o: tar.c star.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) tar.c -o tar.o
untar.o: untar.c star.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) untar.c -o untar.o
general.o: general.c star.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) general.c -o general.o
regular.o: regular.c star.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) regular.c -o regular.o
dir.o: star.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) dir.c -o dir.o
clean:
    \rm -rf *.o star docs
debug: CFLAGS += $(GDBFLAGS)
debug: all
```

**regular.c**

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "star.h"
void regular_untar(FILE *tarf, struct header_ustar *h)
{
    /*getting the file name from prefix/name*/
    char filename[260]={0};
    if(h->prefix[0]){
        strncat(filename,h->prefix,155);
        strcat(filename,"/");
    }
    strncat(filename,h->name,100);
    FILE *fp; //output file
    fp = fopen(filename,"w");
    if(fp ==NULL)
            return;
    /*write file data*/
    unsigned int filesize;
    sscanf(h->size,"%12o",&filesize);
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*filesize);
    fread(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),(size_t)(filesize),tarf);
    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),(size_t)filesize,fp);
    long int  toseek = 512-ftell(tarf)%512;
    if(toseek <512)
        fseek(tarf,toseek,SEEK_CUR);
    fclose(fp);
}
void regular_tar(FILE *tarf, char *filename,struct stat * filestat)
{
    struct header_ustar h;
    bzero(&h,sizeof(struct header_ustar) );
    int len = (int) strlen(filename);
    /*filling in the name,prefix members of the structure*/
    if(len>255)
        return;
    if(len>100){
        int j=154;
        while(filename[j]!='/')
            j--;
        if(len-j>100)
            return;
        strncpy(h.prefix,filename,(size_t)j);
        strncpy(h.name,filename+j+1,(size_t)(len-j-1));
    }
    else
        strcpy(h.name,filename);

    /*getting the uid,gid & rest of the struct members*/
    char *buf=malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*512);
    sprintf(buf,"%08o",filestat->st_uid);
    strncpy(h.uid,buf,8);
    sprintf(buf,"%08o",filestat->st_gid);
    strncpy(h.gid,buf,8);
    sprintf(buf,"%012o",(unsigned int)filestat->st_size);
    strncpy(h.size,buf,12);
    sprintf(buf,"%012o",(unsigned int)filestat->st_mtime);
    strncpy(h.mtime,buf,12);
    h.typeflag='0';
    sprintf(buf,"%08o",filestat->st_mode);
    strncpy(h.mode,buf,8);
    strcpy(h.magic,MAGIC);
    strncpy(h.version,"00",2);
    unsigned int chksum = checksum(&h);
    sprintf(h.checksum,"%06o",chksum);
    h.checksum[7] = ' ';
    fwrite(&h,sizeof(struct header_ustar),1,tarf);
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(filename,"rb");

    bzero(buf,512);
    while((int) fread(buf,sizeof(unsigned char),(size_t)512,fp)!=0){
        fwrite(buf,(size_t)512,sizeof(unsigned char),tarf);
        bzero(buf,512);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

**star.h**

```c
#ifndef __TAR_H__
#define __TAR_H__
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define HELP_MAX 100000
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define MAGIC "ustar"
#define SUCCESS 0
#define ERR -1

/**
 * header_ustar structure
 */
struct header_ustar
{
/**
 * Pathname, stored as a null-terminated string except when all characters in
 * the array contain non-NUL characters including the last character.One common
 * early convention used a trailing "/"character to indicate a directory name,
 */
    char name[100];
//! File mode, stored as an octal number in ASCII.
    char mode[8];
//! User id of owner, as octal numbers in ASCII.
    char uid[8];
//! Group id of owner, as octal numbers in ASCII.
    char gid[8]; 
/**
 * Size of file, as octal number in ASCII. For regular files only,
 * this indicates the amount of data that follows the header. In
 * particular,zero is stored for anything other than regular files.
 */
    char size[12];
/**
 * Modification time of file, as an octal number in ASCII. This
 * indicates the number of seconds since the start of the epoch,
 * 00:00:00 UTC January 1, 1970.
 */
    char mtime[12];
/**
 * Header checksum, stored as an octal number in ASCII. To compute the checksum,
 * set the checksum field to all spaces, then sum all bytes in the header using
 * unsigned arithmetic. This field should be stored as six octal digits followed
 * by a null and a space character.
 */
    char checksum[8];
/**
 * Type of entry. POSIX extended the earlier linkflag field with several new
 * type values:
 *     * '0'   Regular file.
 *     * '1'   Hard link.
 *     * '2'   Symbolic link.
 *     * '3'   Character device node.
 *     * '4'   Block device node.
 *     * '5'   Directory.
 *     * '6'   FIFO node.
 *     *  Other treated as a regular file.
 * Note that in this tar implementation only Regular files and Directories are implemented.
 */
    char typeflag;
/**
 *Not used in my implementation
 */
    char linkname[100];
/**
 * Contains the magic value "ustar" followed by a NUL byte to
 * indicate that this is a POSIX standard archive. Full compliance
 * requires the uname and gname fields be properly set.
 */
    char magic[6];
/**
 * Version. This should be "00" (two copies of the ASCII digit zero) for 
 * POSIX standard archives without the NUL byte.
 */
    char version[2];
/**
 * Not used in my implementation. The uid is used instead.
 */
    char uname[32];
/**
 * Not used in my implementation. The gid is used instead.
 */
    char gname[32];
/**
 * Not used in my implementation.
 */
    char devmajor[8];
/**
 * Not used in my implementation.
 */
    char devminor[8];
/**
 * If the pathname is too long to fit in the 100 bytes provided by name , it can
 * be split at any / character with the first portion going into the prefix
 * field. If the prefix field is not empty, the path name will be in form 
 * of `prefix/name`
 */
    char prefix[155];
/**
 * ustar tape archive is used to store data on 9-track industry-standard 12.7 mm (0.5 in).
 * Data is read and written in form of consecutive logical record each of size 512 bytes.
 * padding is used to make the header logical record fit on 512 byte border.
 */
    char padding[12];
} __attribute__((packed));

/**
 * \breif reads the file from tar archive and write it  
 */
void regular_untar (FILE* tarf, struct header_ustar* h);
/*!
 * \brief writes the tar header to the file content to the tar file
 * \param tarf pointer to the tar file
 * \param filename pathname of the file
 * \param filestat pointer to the structure stat that contains file state info
 * the function regular_tar creates struct header_ustar and fill it with info
 * from the filestat then write this data to the file pointer to by tarf
 * next the content of the file is written all in binary..
 * after the content of file is written the stream tarf is filled with zeros
 * till it is alligned on boundry of 512 bytes
 */
void regular_tar (FILE* tarf, char* filename,struct stat * filestat);
/*!
 * \brief creates directory with the name carried by the header_ustar *h
 * \param h pointer to the ustar_header that contains directory info
 * the dir dir_untar function creates directory with name found in prefix/name
 * members of the struct header_ustar. No persmissions are set on created
 * folder
 */

void dir_untar(struct header_ustar* h);
/*!
 * \brief add directory and its content to the tar archive
 * \param tarf pointer to the tar file structure
 * \param dirname null terminated directory name
 * \param s pointer to the directory state structure
 * the function dir_tar will create struct header_ustar for the directory
 * then write it to the tarf steam then iterate over all the direcotry content
 * and tar them either with dir_tar or with regular_tar accordint to the
 * directory type.
 */
void dir_tar(FILE* tarf, char* dirname, struct stat* s);
/*!
 * read HELP_MAX character from file called help.doc
 * and print write them to stdout
 */

void show_help(void);
/*!
 * \brief calculates the checksum
 *
 * \param h pointer to tar header that will have checksum calculated for
 *
 * for extra information on how checksum is calculated read struct 
 * header_ustar member checksum
 */

unsigned int checksum (const struct header_ustar* h);

/*!
 * \brief create pack list of files into one tar archive
 * \param c number of elementes in the array of strings names
 * \param names the first element in names represent the name of the tar
 * and the rest (c-1) names represent the files/folders to be tarred
 * 
 * tar creates file with Pathnam = names[0] and it decides the type of the
 * given names and call either regular_tar or dir_tar to do both regular file
 * tarring and directory tarring
 */
void tar(int c, char** names);

/*!
 * \brief unpack the tar archive into its original contents
 *
 * \param name the Pathname of the tar archive
 *
 * untar reads header_ustar logical block from the file and use it to determine the type
 * of the file. and then passes this block to either regular_untar or dir_untar based on
 * the member type_flag 
 */
void untar(char* name);

/*!
 * \brief Function thar returns TRUE if the given file path is correct
 * and FALSE otherwise.
 *
 * \param path Pathname of the file.
 *
 * file_exist tries opening file with fopen and returns TRUE if fopen succeeded
 * and FALSE if fopen failed
 */
int file_exist(char* path);

/*!
 * \brief Function that returns 1 if the given struct is
 * valid header_ustar and zero otherwise
 * 
 * \param h pointer to the struct that will be checked
 * 
 * this function makesure that the h->magic is identical to the MAGIC
 * number and that the h->checksum of the struct is the right
 * checksum
 */
int isvalid_tar (const struct header_ustar* h);
#endif
```

**tar.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "star.h"
void tar(int c, char**names){
    int i;
    FILE *tar_file;
    tar_file = fopen(names[0],"wb");
    for(i=1;i<c;i++)
    {
        struct stat s;
        stat(names[i],&s);
        if( S_ISREG(s.st_mode))
            regular_tar(tar_file,names[i],&s);
        else if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode))
            dir_tar(tar_file,names[i],&s);
    }
    for(i=0;i<256;i++){
        int z=0;
        fwrite(&z,sizeof(int),1,tar_file);
    }
    fclose(tar_file);
}
```

**untar.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "star.h"
void untar(char *name)
{
    FILE *tarptr;
    tarptr = fopen(name,"rb");
    struct header_ustar h;
    fread(&h,sizeof(struct header_ustar),1,tarptr);
    while(isvalid_tar(&h)){
        switch(h.typeflag){
            case '0':
                regular_untar(tarptr,&h);
                break;
            case '5':
                dir_untar(&h);
        }
        fread(&h,sizeof(struct header_ustar),1,tarptr);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line: `* \breif reads the file from tar archive and write it`

contains a misspelling of the key word `brief`

For readability/understandability, separate code blocks: (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a blank line

when calling system functions: `fopen()` and `fread()` always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

the `switch()` statements should include a `default:` case so unexpected input, etc is caught and handled

in the file: `untar.c`  the controlling variable for the while() loop should be the call to `fread()`, and have `isvalid()` be in an `if` statement inside the loop,  Then the loop will be properly exited when the `fread()` fails.

The code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using `#define`s or an `enum` to give those magic numbers meaningful names then use those meaningful names throughout the code.  Some of the 'magic' numbers are 100, 256, 154.

The `stat()` function needs a path for the first parameter, not just the file name.

regarding the header file: `star.h`  leading underscores, especially double leading underscores are 'effectively' reserved for the compiler.  Strongly suggest removing the double leading underscores and use the complete file name in the #ifndef, etc statements.  I.E:

```
#ifndef STAR_H
#define STAR_H
...
#endif
```

when calling `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

regarding this line: `long int  toseek = 512-ftell(tarf)%512;`

the `%` operator has a lower precedence than the `-` operator  so the result of the line will be drastically different that what is expected.

Also, if the file is less than 512 bytes long, then the `%` operator will threat the resulting negative value as a very large positive value, again resulting a drastically different value than what is expected.